# FastApi communication with other API

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I am using fastapi very recently and as an exercise I want to connect my fastapi API with a validation service on other server... but I do not know how to do this, I have not found something that will help me in the official documentation.. Will I have to do it with python code? Or is there a way?

[FastApi docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com)

Comment: For connecting to other REST service, use `requests` library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to code it with Python.

If you're using async you should use a HTTP client that is also async, for example [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

```py
import aiohttp

@app.get("/")
async def slow_route():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://validation_service.com") as resp:
            data = await resp.text()
            # do something with data
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer certainly works, but it is not an effective solution. With each request, the `ClientSession` is closed, so we lose the advantage [0] of `ClientSession`: connection pooling, keepalives, etc. etc.

We can use the `startup` and `shutdown` events [1] in FastAPI, which are triggered when the server starts and shuts down respectively. In these events it is possible to create a `ClientSession` instance and use it during the runtime of the whole application (and therefore utilize its full potential).

The `ClientSession` instance is stored in the application state. [2]

Here I answered a very similar question in the context of the aiohttp server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850857/752142

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import asyncio
from typing import Final

from aiohttp import ClientSession
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request

app: Final = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    setattr(app.state, "client_session", ClientSession(raise_for_status=True))


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await asyncio.wait((app.state.client_session.close()), timeout=5.0)


def client_session_dep(request: Request) -> ClientSession:
    return request.app.state.client_session


@app.get("/")
async def root(
    client_session: ClientSession = Depends(client_session_dep),
) -> str:
    async with client_session.get(
        "https://example.com/", raise_for_status=True
    ) as the_response:
        return await the_response.text()
```

- [0] https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html
- [1] https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/
- [2] https://www.starlette.io/applications/#storing-state-on-the-app-instance

Answer (score 0):

The `startup` and `shutdown` event handling is deprecated (See [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#alternative-events-deprecated)).

But you could use [`lifespan`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#alternative-events-deprecated) now:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from fastapi import Request
from httpx import AsyncClient

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    setattr(app.state, "client_session", AsyncClient())
    yield
    await app.state.client_session.aclose()


def client_session_dep(request: Request) -> AsyncClient:
    return request.app.state.client_session


@app.get("/")
async def root(
    client_session: AsyncClient = Depends(client_session_dep),
) -> str:
    response = await client_session.get('https://www.example.com/')
    return response.text()
```