# How to share (initialize and close) aiohttp.ClientSession between Django async views to use connection pooling

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Django supports [async views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/async/#async-views) since version 3.1, so it's great for non-blocking calls to e.g. external HTTP APIs (using, for example, [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)).

I [often see](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-async-views/) the following code sample, which I think is conceptually wrong (although it works perfectly fine):

```py
import aiohttp
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse

async def view_bad_example1(request: HttpRequest):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://example.com/") as example_response:
            response_text = await example_response.text()
            return HttpResponse(response_text[:42], content_type="text/plain")
```

This code creates a `ClientSession` for each incoming request, which is inefficient. `aiohttp` cannot then use e.g. connection pooling.

> Don’t create a session per request. Most likely you need a session per
> application which performs all requests altogether.
>
> Source: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request

The same applies to httpx:

> On the other hand, a Client instance uses HTTP connection pooling.
> This means that when you make several requests to the same host, the
> Client will reuse the underlying TCP connection, instead of recreating
> one for every single request.
>
> Source: https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#why-use-a-client

Is there any way to globally instantiate `aiohttp.ClientSession` in Django so that this instance can be shared across multiple requests? Don't forget that `ClientSession` must be created in a running eventloop ([Why is creating a ClientSession outside of an event loop dangerous?](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-is-creating-a-clientsession-outside-of-an-event-loop-dangerous)), so we can't instantiate it e.g. in Django settings or as a module-level variable.

The closest I got is this code. However, I think this code is ugly and doesn't address e.g. closing the session.

```py
CLIENT_SESSSION = None

async def view_bad_example2(request: HttpRequest):
    global CLIENT_SESSSION

    if not CLIENT_SESSSION:
        CLIENT_SESSSION = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    example_response = await CLIENT_SESSSION.get("https://example.com/")
    response_text = await example_response.text()

    return HttpResponse(response_text[:42], content_type="text/plain")
```

Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of [Events from FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/) that can be used to [create/close some resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70865738/752142) in an async context.

By the way here is a performance comparison using k6 between the two views:

- `view_bad_example1`: `avg=1.32s min=900.86ms med=1.14s max=2.22s p(90)=2s p(95)=2.1s`
- `view_bad_example2`: `avg=930.82ms min=528.28ms med=814.31ms max=1.66s p(90)=1.41s  p(95)=1.52s`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django doesn't implement the ASGI Lifespan protocol.
Ref: https://github.com/django/django/pull/13636

Starlette [does](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b588ebed36c2934b33ad3b0221d79bd8b7a4817f/starlette/routing.py#L668). FastAPI directly uses Starlette's implementation of event handlers.

Here's how you can achieve that with Django:

1. Implement the ASGI Lifespan protocol in a subclass of Django's `ASGIHandler`.

```py
import django
from django.core.asgi import ASGIHandler


class MyASGIHandler(ASGIHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.on_shutdown = []

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        if scope['type'] == 'lifespan':
            while True:
                message = await receive()
                if message['type'] == 'lifespan.startup':
                    # Do some startup here!
                    await send({'type': 'lifespan.startup.complete'})
                elif message['type'] == 'lifespan.shutdown':
                    # Do some shutdown here!
                    await self.shutdown()
                    await send({'type': 'lifespan.shutdown.complete'})
                    return
        await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)

    async def shutdown(self):
        for handler in self.on_shutdown:
            if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(handler):
                await handler()
            else:
                handler()


def my_get_asgi_application():
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    return MyASGIHandler()
```

2. Replace the `application` in asgi.py.

```py
# application = get_asgi_application()
application = my_get_asgi_application()
```

3. Implement a helper `get_client_session` to share the instance:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from .asgi import application

CLIENT_SESSSION = None

_lock = asyncio.Lock()


async def get_client_session():
    global CLIENT_SESSSION

    async with _lock:
        if not CLIENT_SESSSION:
            CLIENT_SESSSION = aiohttp.ClientSession()
            application.on_shutdown.append(CLIENT_SESSSION.close)

    return CLIENT_SESSSION
```

Usage:

```py
async def view(request: HttpRequest):
    session = await get_client_session()
    
    example_response = await session.get("https://example.com/")
    response_text = await example_response.text()

    return HttpResponse(response_text[:42], content_type="text/plain")
```